# Sorting a string vector in C++ with a special value to place at the end

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

I'm trying to make a function that sorts a vector of strings with this criteria:

All strings= "NULL" must go to the end of the vector and decreasing from there. The rest of the strings must keep their order.

For example given:

```
{"Potato", "NULL", "NULL", "Charmander" , "Spaghetti", "NULL"}
```

the output should be:

```
{"Potato","Charmander","Spaghetti","NULL","NULL","NULL"}
```

I tried with this but it did not quite work:

```
bool comp(string i, string j){
    if(i=="NULL"){return i>j;}
     if (j=="NULL") {return i<j;}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `comp` function needs to answer the question "does `i` come before `j`?"  That's not what your implementation is doing given your criteria for sorting.

Comment: What do you mean "decreasing from there" if everything else needs to keep its order? All `"NULL"`s should compare equal; they can't be decreasing.

Comment: Since I'm not sure what you're going for, this is a comment not an answer, but I think [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) is probably useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of two things:

1. First take care of the "NULL"s, then sort the other strings the naive way we regularly would
2. Sort all string using the more complex ordering you defined

#### Handling "NULL"s first

The standard library has a ["partition" algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition), which will move all elements matching a certain criterion to the end of the string.

```
std::vector<string> vec {
    "Potato", "NULL", "NULL", "Charmander" , "Spaghetti", "NULL"
};
auto is_not_null = [](const std::string& s) { return s != "NULL"; } 
auto nulls_start = std::partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), is_not_null);
auto non_nulls_end = nulls_start;
std::sort(vec.begin(), non_nulls_end);
```

#### Sort with a complex comparison

```
std::vector<string> vec {
    "Potato", "NULL", "NULL", "Charmander" , "Spaghetti", "NULL"
};
auto comparator = 
    [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
    {
        return rhs == "NULL" or lhs <= rhs; 
    };
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comparator);
```

Note the difference between the comparison here and your `comp()` function. The comparator answers question "should the first string I got come before the second string?" - and your `comp()` function just doesn't give an answer that corresponds to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use partition algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    vector<string> vec {
        "Potato", "NULL", "NULL", "Charmander" , "Spaghetti", "NULL"
    };

    partition(begin(vec), end(vec), // Partition the values
               [](const string& s) { return s != "NULL"; });


    copy(begin(vec), end(vec), ostream_iterator<string>{cout, " "});
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
// RESULT: Potato Spaghetti Charmander NULL NULL NULL
```

NOTE: If you need to maintain relative ordering use stable_partition instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own version of function that puts some strings to the end i.e:

```
namespace myAlgo {
        template<typename ForwardIter, class T >
        ForwardIter moveToEnd(ForwardIter first, ForwardIter last, const T& value) {
            if (first == last) {
                return first;
            }
            ForwardIter fasterFirst = first;
            //Shift strings that do not match value to the left in stable manner
            while (++fasterFirst != last) {
                if (*fasterFirst != value) {
                    *++first = *fasterFirst;
                }
            }
            ForwardIter pivot = first;
            //Fill rest with value
            while (first != last) {
                *++first = value;
            }
    return pivot;
    }
}
```

Then just:

```
myAlgo::moveToEnd(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "NULL");
```